# Where can I find questions marked favorite on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Where can I find questions marked favorite on Stack Overflow?

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work

Comment: here is the link of your marked favorite question https://stackoverflow.com/users/10504840/lordstack?tab=favorites

Answer (score 6):

*favorite* is now renamed as *saves*

Comment: A reference is *[Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/)* (MSE. 2022-09-23).

Answer (score 3):

[Click here to see your favorites question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites)

Open your profile and click on the *favorites* tab.

Like the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate.  See Cauchy Schwarz's answer as "favorites" is now saves.

Answer (score 2):

Open your profile by clicking on your profile pic. And inside it, click on the favourites tab. There you can see the questions marked as favourite.

Answer (score -8):

I was going to be a jerk and say "you could write a Python script to do it".

But I actually tried because I don't know web scraping and it was actually fun.

```
import re
import urllib.request

userID=input('enter stack overflow ID ')

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/'+userID+'?tab=favorites'

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

data1 = data.decode('utf-8')

numberFav=re.search("<span class='count'>",data1)
numberFav=data1[numberFav.end():numberFav.end()+1]

urlFav=[]
for _ in range(int(numberFav)):

    m = re.search('<div class="summary">', data1)
    pad=54
    start = m.start() + pad

    s=re.search('class="question-hyperlink">', data1[start:])

    end = start + s.start() -2

    newString = data1[start:end]
    urlFav.append('stackoverflow.com'+newString)
    data1=data1[start:]

for i in range(len(urlFav)):
    print('{}\n'.format(urlFav[i]))

# for your ID 10504840 it was stackoverflow.com/questions/6171630/why-isnt-operator-overloading-for-pointers-allowed-to-work
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to know where to look on the page for making a python script ! (I know you did it for the fun, but you should use beautifulsoup, it helps a lot in scrapping and you don't have to use magic numbers in your code anymore (such as `-2`) )

Comment: If you want to write a script might as well use the API for it instead of scraping: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-favorites